# Swift compatibility

Tags: ios, swift

This might be a stupid question, but I am trying to grasp the concept of new swift versions as it is not perfectly clear to me.
Along with iOS 8.3, Apple introduced Swift 1.2.
If developing an app that is compatible with iOS 8.0.0 and up in Swift, how will the new Swift version affect the older iOS versions? Can I safely use the newest Swift syntax without concern for those users still on iOS 8.0.0?
Thanks for any feedback.
Best Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a stupid question. Don't worry, because right now the Swift interpreter is built into *each individual app*, not the system it runs on. So changes in Swift don't change anything: each app continues to run, because it *contains* the Swift version it was compiled with.

Answer (score 2):

I believe, your language or coding pattern(Swift 1.2) is not related to the comparability of your iOS version. Briefly, don't worry about the iOS version update; you can go ahead with Swift 1.2.

Your apps behavior specially UI may be affected by the iOS version change but not the language version. Just to clarify, my experience says, when apple introduces a new iOS version, it tries to support the older version's functionality and properties as much as possible. Most of the time, when there is a big leap like from iOS 6.0 to iOS 7.0 or 8.0, there can be some deprecations; even in that case, you don't have to worry too much. For example, upto iOS 7.0 apple provided UISearchDisplayController for searching which is deprecated in iOS 8.0 and is substituted by UISearchController whose functionality is fundamentally same. So, even after I updated my app's UI from iOS7 to iOS8, I am still using UISearchDisplayController without any issue.

In fact, if you have developed your app using iOS 8.0 SDK, then for 8.3 SDK, you may not even find any deprecations, let alone functionality or behavior change.